# What's the difference between git stash apply and git stash apply --index?

Tags: git

Whenever I run `git stash apply` and `git stash apply --index` after having done `git stash -a` I get the same result even though my WIP directory has staged changes, unstaged (but tracked changes) and untracked files.

Is this normal? Shouldn't `git stash apply` not return the index?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation of `git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)?

Comment: I did but that did not help me understand the issue.

Comment: I'd like to see an example of when `git stash apply` without `--index` restored the index changes (and your Git version, too). The stash code has undergone various revisions over time, but the current (Git 2.12+) code should not behave that way.

Comment: Might be that my Git version is not updated?

Answer (score 3):

Using `git stash apply` the changes to your files were reapplied, but the file(s) you staged before wouldn't be re-staged.

If you want to do that, you could add the `--index` option to tell the command to try to reapply the staged changes.

Comment: That's the thing I don't understand...let's say I have:

* File A from the last commit, with some updates but not on the stage.
* File B on the index.
* File C untracked.

Using `git stash -a` brings me back to the previous version of file A which is what I want, while files B and C disappear. Now if I use `git stash apply` or `git stash apply --index` in both cases the file B is back on the stage. Shouldn't it be back only if I put the `--index` option?

(Apologize for the bad formatting, seems like the comments can't be formatted much...)

Comment: I agree, if the --index option is used, should reinstate the index changes... so no index option should do (in theory) the opposite, so I'm now confused too...

Answer (score 0):

While git stage apply --index should restore the index in addition of applying a stashed change, its behavior has changed with Git 2.36 (Q2 2022).

It does not output as much as before.

"[`git stash`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6d51217467afe5303349cb5c57b6b131201f73f3/Documentation/git-stash.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash))</sup> does not allow subcommands it internally runs as its implementation detail, except for "[`git reset`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6d51217467afe5303349cb5c57b6b131201f73f3/Documentation/git-reset.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset))</sup>, to emit messages; now "`git reset`" part has also been squelched.

See [commit 5891c76](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5891c76cd012536a5bb833e512f7262a4b4358c1) (24 Mar 2022) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
See [commit 7cff676](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7cff6765fe5c1ce97f4afba9432c8aa5c5f877ba), [commit 2efc9b8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2efc9b84e5e9ea063ecfb2f813cb56653a03c10a), [commit 45bf762](https://github.com/git/git/commit/45bf76284b40856e47e8809e952167f0316b8a99) (23 Mar 2022), and [commit 4b8b0f6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4b8b0f6fa2778c1f9c373620e3f07787543914c6), [commit d492abb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d492abb0ae4a00c5647189b22f7c130fb364e700), [commit 9396251](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9396251b371b9475b60461ddb27bd22282c86d79), [commit fd56fba](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fd56fba97f26bf668749207efd6a45aee2e2f57c), [commit e86ec71](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e86ec71d20d14861e4a3d047800d3ea3099c946d) (15 Mar 2022) by [Victoria Dye (`vdye`)](https://github.com/vdye).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6d51217](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6d51217467afe5303349cb5c57b6b131201f73f3), 30 Mar 2022)</sup>

> ### [`stash`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4b8b0f6fa2778c1f9c373620e3f07787543914c6): make internal resets quiet and refresh index
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Victoria Dye</sup>

> Add the options '`-q`' and '`--refresh`' to the '[`git reset`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4b8b0f6fa2778c1f9c373620e3f07787543914c6/Documentation/git-reset.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset))</sup> executed in '`reset_head()`', and '`--refresh`' to the '[`git reset -q`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4b8b0f6fa2778c1f9c373620e3f07787543914c6/Documentation/git-reset.txt#L106)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#Documentation/git-reset.txt--q))</sup> executed in '`do_push_stash(...)`'.
>
> '`stash`' is implemented such that `git` commands invoked as part of it (e.g., '`clean`', '`read-tree`', '`reset`', etc.) have their informational output *silenced*.
>
> However, the '`reset`' in '`reset_head()`' is *not* called with '`-q`', leading to the potential for a misleading printout from '[`git stash apply --index`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4b8b0f6fa2778c1f9c373620e3f07787543914c6/Documentation/git-stash.txt#L178)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt---index))</sup> if the stash included a removed file:
>
> ```
> Unstaged changes after reset: D      <deleted file>
> ```
>
> Not only is this confusing in its own right (since, after the reset, '[`git stash`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4b8b0f6fa2778c1f9c373620e3f07787543914c6/Documentation/git-stash.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash))</sup> execution would stage the deletion in the index), it would be printed even when the stash was applied with the '`-q`' option.
>
> As a result, the messaging is removed entirely by calling '[`git status`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4b8b0f6fa2778c1f9c373620e3f07787543914c6/Documentation/git-status.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status))</sup> with '`-q`'.
>
> Additionally, because the default behavior of '`git reset -q`' is to skip refreshing the index, but later operations in '`git stash`' subcommands expect a non-stale index, enable '`--refresh`' as well.