# I read about git-stash and don't understand what the `-index` does

Tags: git, git-stash

I read about [git-stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) and dont understand what the `-index` does
I understand what stash does, apply pop ans so on but this `-index` not

I read [whats-the-difference-between-git-stash-apply-and-git-stash-apply-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48645729/whats-the-difference-between-git-stash-apply-and-git-stash-apply-index) but don't understand it. Would someone draw a scenario?

> --index This option is only valid for pop and apply commands.
>
> Tries to reinstate not only the working tree’s changes, but also the
> index’s ones. However, this can fail, when you have conflicts (which
> are stored in the index, where you therefore can no longer apply the
> changes as they were originally).

Comment: [LeGEC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63909951/1256452) is correct, but unless you know what Git's index *is*, it still won't make a lot of sense to you. You should learn about Git's index, because Git insists on shoving it in your face now and then. :-)

Comment: Why is it called "index" but when using Git anywhere it's called staging aria?

Comment: It actually has *three* names: "the index", "the staging area", and "the cache". The original name was the index, and some commands that work with it use that name: `git update-index` for instance. But that name doesn't *mean* anything, so `git diff` added `--cached` to refer to the cached copy of files that's *in* the index, and `git rm` has `--cached` to remove the index copy of a file. But that name is poor as well, so someone invented *staging area*, which is perhaps the best of the three names, but also the *newest* one.

Comment: In short, it was a kind of historical mistake, which is now preserved for eternity. The term *staging area* describes how one *uses* the thing, but it has an extra role during conflicted merges, so I myself tend to use the old name, "index".

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you work on your `master` branch, and that your master branch contains a file `foo.txt`, whose content is :

```
first line: master
```

You edit that file, and add a new line :

```
first line: master
second line: index
```

and you run `git add foo.txt` but don't commit yet ;
before committing, you add a third line :

```
first line: master
second line: index
third line: worktree
```

Now, for some reason,  you run `git stash`.

If you restore your stash using `git stash pop` or `git stash apply`, the 2 lines version will be "forgotten", you will only get back the 3 lines version, and it will be placed in the index.

If you add `--index`, however, you will retrieve the 2 lines version in the index, and the 3 lines version on disk, not added yet.

---

The caveat about the index is: if you try to reapply the stash on a different commit, and restoring the stashed changes trigger conflicts : git uses the index to store the conflicting versions, and `git stash` may not be able to separate the worktree version and the indexed version.

---

When you have both staged files and modified-but-unstaged files, it can be useful to get back to that state.

The default behavior of `git stash pop / git stash apply` is to restore everything in the index, so you would have to manually select the files you want to actually stage and the files you want to unstage.

If your intention is to have "what was staged" in the index, and not mix it with "what was not staged", that's when the `--index` comes in handy.

That being said, I, for one, most often don't use `--index` when restoring my stash.

Comment: Good explanation Thanks

Comment: I run a test project in VSCode and try to understand why `--index"` is useful. I mean I "stash" and can pop that stash anywhere it's a great feature I always "know" what I stashed right! Using the `--index` bring back something that is already in the stashed files I think. Dont get when `--index`is usefull

Comment: Isn't there some git playground somewhere on Internet? I mean interactivity to learn git